# AutoCompleteTextView is not showing strings loaded from the Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

I want make a AutoCompleteTextview which will load previously saved suggestion from the internal storage. I successfully loaded the strings from the internal storage to a string array(i used logging to check....).

then as i loaded the string array to an adapter and set the adapter to the AutoCompleteTextview, after that the AutoCompleteTextview is not showing the suggestion-strings which i loaded from the Internal Storage but it is showing the suggestion-string(s) which i loaded to the string array at runtime.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //this is the array where i am trying to save my data into 
    loadedString=new String[1];
    loadedString[0]="the pre-loaded String"

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, loadedString);


    atcv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);

    int objectCounter = 0;       

    try {

        FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput(FILENAME);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String temp;


        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //here i am calculating the lines of my data-file 
        //as 1 line contains 1 string object
        //so that i can initialize the string array


         objectCounter++;
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //intializing the array
    // objectCounter+1 and index =1 because i loaded an object before

      loadedString = new String[objectCounter+1];

     int index = 1;  


    try {

        FileInputStream fis = this.openFileInput(FILENAME);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);


        String temp;


        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {


            loadedString[index] = temp;
            index++;
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    atcv.setAdapter(adapter);
    atcv.setThreshold(1);


}
```

this is the method i am using to save the data

```
 public void saver(View view) {

      String string;


         if(actv.getText()!=null){
            advice = advices.getText().toString();}

        advice=advice+"\n";


        try{

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, context.MODE_APPEND);

        fos.write(advice.getBytes());
        fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "File  saved" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "File could not be saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Please help. Note that i used notifyDataSetChanged() method. I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that i used notifyDataSetChanged() method

In your case, that is useless. The `ArrayAdapter` will continue to use your old `String[1]`. It does not know about your new `String[]`.

First, do not do disk I/O on the main application thread, as you are doing here. Use some form of background operation, like an `AsyncTask`.

Second, do not read the data in twice, as that is twice as slow for the user. For example, you could use a data structure like `ArrayList<String>`, which can expand its size on the fly.

Then, do not create the `ArrayAdapter` until after you have loaded the strings.